# PendingIntent Multiple Task

Tags: java, android

Hello this is my first question :3 ,

So i have this code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, vidfolder.class); 
 intent.putExtra("foo", fid);       


 PendingIntent pIntent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    context,
                    0,
                    intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            );

     Notification n = new Notification.Builder(context)
            .setContentTitle( "(" + fid + ") "   + fidName )
            .setContentText("Your folder is ready")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .setVibrate(new long[] {0, 1000, 200,1000 })
    .setDefaults( Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | 
    Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS )

            .setContentIntent(pIntent).setAutoCancel(true)
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .setStyle(new 
   Notification.BigTextStyle().bigText(longText))
            .build();
         NotificationManager notificationManager = 
     (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);    
     int m = (int) ((new Date().getTime() / 1000L) % Integer.MAX_VALUE);
final int random = new Random().nextInt(999) + 26;
int m2 = m * random;
    notificationManager.notify(m2, n);
```

it's will generate multiple notifications let say

Folder 1 is reaady
Folder 2 is ready

and in my vidfolder i am retreiving the data with this code

```
   Intent intent = getIntent();
   String sharedText = intent.getStringExtra("foo");
```

my problem is when 2 folders are ready i get 2 notifications but they both have the same Extra ( the one of the last notification ) ,

How can i make multiple pending intents :/

Also i tried to change FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT to 0 , after i do this the second notification don't work :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oh i changed my code to

```
          int m3 = (int) ((new Date().getTime() / 1000L) % 
  Integer.MAX_VALUE);
final int random3 = new Random().nextInt(999) + 26;
int m4 = m3 * random3;

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, vidfolder.class); 
   intent.putExtra("foo", fid);     


      PendingIntent pIntent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    context,
                    m4,
                    intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            );
```

it's working now :)